# Strange problem with VLC 3.0.12 on Kubuntu 21.04

Tags: kde, vlc, crash

A strange problem occurred with VLC 3.0.12 on Kubuntu 21.04. Basically if I go to open a video while it is in use by another program (for example I had opened a video while it was in use from the system settings, because I use a plugin to have the animated wallpaper, while the second time I still opened the same video but this time it was in use by OpenShot) the system crashes completely. Only the pointer stuck on a black background remains and no key combination (for example the classic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> ) manages to make me open a text shell from which I can reboot, so I am forced to power off the system from the shutdown key.

Has this ever happened to any of you?  Do you know if maybe it's a known bug?